# assert whether a domain class table is empty in a grails service

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Some static method did not get injected to grails services. But What if I wanna assert whether a domain class table is empty in a service?

Like in a controller, I can do:

```
assert DomainClass.count()==0
```

What is the alternative in a grails service or a grails domain class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it does not work as is, but it worked for me when I wrapped the assertion in braces

```
assert (DomainClass.count()==0)
```

Comment: I tested this in a Grails Service